# How to convert .dll to .jnilib?

Tags: java

When I use java to develop a project, I need to use a .dll library file provided by others. I encountered a problem when loading this file in java. That is, no xxx in java.library.path, I can confirm that there is this .dll file in this path. Later I learned that only .jnilib files are used under macos?
I am using macos system, but now I only have one .dll file and no other files. Is it the only way to convert dll to jnilib? So how to solve it?
Or is there some other method?